# how can i store values in array using foreach loop...?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am working under Opencart. My big problem is should store values in array for displaying result. And my question is >> I want to fetch product in Db which under the particular location. for example if the location Bangalore, Bangalore products come alone.

query Shown below:

```
public function getvendorsbycity($city,$products)

{
    $selected_vendor = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "vendors where city='".$city."'");

    if(isset($selected_vendor->rows) && !empty($selected_vendor->rows))
    {
        $i=0;
        foreach($selected_vendor->rows as $val)
        {

            $selected_array=array();
            if(isset($products) && !empty($products))
            {

                foreach($products as $p_val)
                {


                    $selected_products = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "vendor v LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON v.vproduct_id=pd.product_id WHERE vendor='".$val['vendor_id']."' AND pd.name LIKE '%".$p_val['name']."%'");

                    if(isset($selected_products->rows) && !empty($selected_products->rows))
                    {
                        $selected_array[]=$selected_products->rows;
                    //I am getting result here..!

                    }
                }
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }

    //I could't get result here.! I should return the array here.
    return $selected_array;
}
```

Can any one help me..! Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change

```
$selected_array[]=$selected_products->rows;  
//I am getting result here..!
```

to

```
$selected_array[$i][]=$selected_products->rows;
```

and try what you get

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getvendorsbycity($city,$products)
{
    $selected_vendor = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "vendors where city='".$city."'");
    $selected_array=array(); // we should create array here. so that we can return the result at end.
    if(isset($selected_vendor->rows) && !empty($selected_vendor->rows))
    {
        $i=0;
       //$selected_array=array(); -> its my mistake.(I wrongly created array over here.)
        foreach($selected_vendor->rows as $val)
        {


            if(isset($products) && !empty($products))
            {

                foreach($products as $p_val)
                {


                    $selected_products = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "vendor v LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON v.vproduct_id=pd.product_id WHERE vendor='".$val['vendor_id']."' AND pd.name LIKE '%".$p_val['name']."%'");


                    if(isset($selected_products->rows) && !empty($selected_products->rows))
                    {
                        $selected_array[]=$selected_products->rows;
                    }
                }
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }

    return $selected_array;
}
```

}